# How can I deal with a case in jQuery where an anchor's text value is changed to ""?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is the code: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdtC2/)

1. I have a form where the `a` text values can be edited by dblclicking on the link, or clicking inside the `div` the `a` is inside.
2. Onblur, the value in the input box that is shown on the conditions in 1. is assigned to the text value of the `a`.

**The Problem:** when you leave the input empty and blur it, it sets the `a`'s text to `""`. At this point the `div` around it collapses and becomes inaccessible to the user.

How can I prevent this collapse from happening?

Comment: Your question isn't clear - can you explain in greater detail what should happen and what's not working?

Comment: My understanding is the URL textbox disappears after it is cleared of text.  He wants to be able to click again and it will reappear.

Comment: i made an update of the question, thanks @wirey for the explanation, yes, it dispersal after i clear the input and need if it's empty just then to reappear the input

Comment: just add a default width and height to it

Comment: @Abude: I have added my answer. Check it out **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11164224/500725)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this way, your problem will be sorted out.

On blur, just check the value length is zero then show the input field else show the hyperlink.

```
$('#url0, #url1').each(
    function(index, element){
        $(element).blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length == 0)
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide().prev().show().find('a').html(this.value);
        });
    }    
);
```

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EdtC2/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, that is what i'm talking about :) not css problem :)

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you again, but the problem isn't solve completely, there's a very big problem, when you edit the link and then click out, the hyperlink should be the updated link not the one before, can we fix this please ? thanks a lot!

Comment: can you help me with another question please ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this mate?

http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/EdtC2/4/

```
$('#url0, #url1').each(
    function(index, element){
        $(element).blur(function(){
        this.value == "" ? $(this).hide().prev().show().find('a').html("[insert text here]") : $(this).hide().prev().show().find('a').html(this.value);
    })
    }    
);
```

If the input box is empty, it sets the `a` to '[insert text here]'. Or do you want a situation where it's effectively invisible? If that's the case, you could always change the text colour to match the background, for example?

Comment: yes, that's the answer, but another user already answered before you :(, thanks a lot for your time bro

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you again, but the problem isn't solve completely, there's a very big problem, when you edit the link and then click out, the hyperlink should be the updated link not the one before, can we fix this please http://jsfiddle.net/NJPNj/? thanks a lot!

Comment: resolved with your earlier post on other question of mine :) http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/pFyNY/2/, i will ask another question realated on this and posted here to you, thanks bro :)

Comment: here's my new question man: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188573/how-do-i-separate-my-urls-in-textarea-by-rows-jquery

Comment: Hi man, did you have sometime to look at my problem in that question? please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug at all. Your `a` tag is empty, it collapses.

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EdtC2/2/) to see. You need to set some css on it to make it not collapse. For example, the border makes it work as expected. Adding a padding, or margin would work too. Making it display inline-block also fixes it without any extra border, padding, or margin.

```
.a0 a {
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: i see the demo of you and correct is working, but on my page doesn't, is making both input and <a> attributes display :none after clearing the field

Comment: I just used your jsfiddle... if it's not working in your code then the issue is somewhere else and you'll have to provide more detail.

Comment: i tried with `display: inline-block;` and not working, but with border is working, need to make some how invisible though

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EdtC2/1/).

I simply added a border,default width and height so that the div is visible / clickable even after the input is removed. You might not need to do that.

Comment: i see the demo of you and correct is working, but on my page doesn't, is making both input and <a> attributes display :none after clearing the field

Comment: I added the width and height on the style attribute of the class="a0" div. You could add them in your itself like @sachleen suggested. However make sure that the rules are not overridden!